# Можно ли использовать переменную, если известно её имя в виде строки?

Tags: javascript

Есть код:

```
let x = 5;
let formula = '2 + 4';
ley y = ...;
```

Как мне с помощью этого присвоить новой переменной `y` значение по формуле `'2 + 4'`?
Формулу я могу преобразовать в такой массив: `['2', '+', '4']`. Далее найти в массиве математическую(ие) операцию(ии), получить результат этой математической операции с двумя операндами, находящимися в массиве слева и справа от неё.

А как быть в таком случае:

```
let x = 5;
let formula = 'x + 4';
let y = ...;
```

? Ведь тогда у меня получится `['x', '+', '4']`. Я не могу посчитать это с помощью имеющейся переменной `x`. `eval` не рассматривается. Именно ему альтернативу и ищу. Также хотелось бы без библиотек, хотя они допустимы.

Comment: Ответ обновлён.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если переменная глобальная (что вряд ли), то её можно достать из window. В остальных случаях лучше сложить допустимые переменные в объект и брать их оттуда. Аналогично функции стоит сложить в словарь.

Если приоритеты всех операций одинаковы, то решение довольно простое:

```js
var vars = { x: 5, y: 7 }

var fs = {
  '+': (x, y) => x + y,
  '-': (x, y) => x - y,
}

function extractValue(operand) {
  return operand == +operand ? +operand : vars[operand]
}

var formula = ['x', '+', '4', '-', 'y']
var res = extractValue(formula[0])

for (var q=1; q<formula.length; q+=2) {
  res = fs[formula[q]](res, extractValue(formula[q+1]))
}

console.log(res)
```

Если приоритеты различны, то имеет смысл парсить формулу не в строку, а в дерево:

```js
var vars = { x: 5, y: 7 }

var fs = {
  '+': (x, y) => x + y,
  '-': (x, y) => x - y,
  '*': (x, y) => x * y,
  '/': (x, y) => x / y,
}

var formula = { // x + 3 * y
  op: '+',
  left: 'x',
  right: {
    op: '*',
    left: '3',
    right: 'y'
  }
}

function calc(v) {
  return typeof v === 'string'
         ? v == +v ? +v : vars[v]
         : fs[v.op](calc(v.left), calc(v.right))
}

console.log(calc(formula))
```

Comment: Если в вашем коде формулу изменить на `2 * 12 - 2 / 8`, даже без переменных, то ответ уже получится неверным, а подстановка переменной с помощью объекта выглядит топорной, как костыль (такая мысль у меня тоже была). Я надеялся, что есть в js встроенное средство для решения моей проблемы. Но, всё равно, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: 1. Для `2 * 12 - 2 / 8` всё работает, скорее всего ты неверно составил дерево. Надо было так: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiEhf.png `{
  op: '-',
  left: {
    op: '*',
    left: '2',
    right: '12'
  },
  right: {
    op: '/',
    left: '2',
    right: '8'
  }
}` 2. Подстановка с помощью объекта - наоборот круто.

Comment: @Don2Quixote, кстати, лучше при парсинге уже разделять имена и числа, чтобы потом не проверять.

Comment: Да, я действительно не так составил дерево. А если так: `2 - 12 * 2 + 8`?

`{  op: '*',
 left: {
  op: '-',
  left: '2',
  right: '12'
 },
 right: {
  op: '+',
  left: '2',
  right: '8'
 } 
}`

Comment: @Don2Quixote, и сейчас у тебя дерево неверное

Comment: @Don2Quixote, вот такая структура: `{ op: '+', left: { op: '-', ... }, right: 8}`.

Comment: @Don2Quixote, вот, можешь почитать: http://e-maxx.ru/algo/expressions_parsing. Хотя я обычно не так делаю.